# are controllers necessary to send flash messages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, flash-message

this is kind of a newbie question, sorry but...if a model has no controllers, how could i perform a

```
flash[:notice]?
```

for example in

https://github.com/tute/merit

i noticed that it just has models and no controllers. i know that it would be wise to put the flash message inside a controller as opposed to the methods that get executed in the models, but.... how can i do this if there is no controller?

i could try to create one but then doesn't each action in the controller correspond to a page in the view?

certain methods are being executed in the models and i want to be able to add a flash[:notice] whenever they get executed but...how would i do this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still set flash messages in a controller (or anywhere else the session can be accessed, technically). Merit is just an add-on for Rails, not a replacement. You would still use controllers in your application to handle requests from the user.